# VB String Recognition of a zipcode?

Tags: vb.net

I am having to parse a file for mailing addresses... The problem is somelines contain a address and some do not.... The ones that do not contain a mailing address also do not have a zip code... Is there any string pattern match i could use to manage checking for the zip code??? something like

```
IF not string.isnullorEmpty(_Customer) then
    If _Customer"" ZIP CODE STRING TEST "" THEN
     {do what it should if its is true}
    Else
     {Do something else}
    End If
end if
```

Comment: Do you process canadian or other international addresses? that can change the answer dramatically.

Comment: No its only US zip codes

Comment: See I have to work with a file that has all the mailing addresses, state, zip, and other information run together on one line... I have the parser working to handle the processing of that part already... Some lines only contain a company name though which means I need to check for a zip code before sending to the parser..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends how complex you want your zip code checking to be, here's a method we use to validate US and Canadian Postal Codes:

```
Public Shared Function ValidZip(ByVal cZip As String) As Boolean
    'Check if zip code is either NNNNN-NNNN, NNNNN, ANA NAN 
    Dim rZip As New Regex("^((\d{5}-\d{4})|(\d{5})|([A-Z]\d[A-Z]\s\d[A-Z]\d))$", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
    If Not rZip.IsMatch(cZip) Then
        Return False
    End If

    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: I was just about to post similar regex.

Comment: This is a problem.... The string that I am checking to see if a zip code is present in is 60 characters long... Wont this only work if the zip code is specifically sent to it? Or will it parse the string and only return true if a zip is found?

Comment: Just remove the leading ^ and trailing $ from the regex.